# What are the differences between Portlet and gadgets in Liferay Portal

Tags: liferay, portlet

I'm developing a web page made ​​using the Liferay Portal and I've developed a portlet but I would like to know and understand what the differences are developing a gadget and a Portlet in Liferay. I am intending to develop a gadget if it is best for the situation that I encounter.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [Liferay's blog](http://www.liferay.com/web/alberto.montero/blog/-/blogs/gadgets-and-widgets%3a-using-liferay-as-a-mashup-platform)

Basically, you create a portlet and enable sharing of it as a widget.